# Rxjs: got stuck with returning an array of arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I got stucked with types at returning array from `map` and providing it to `filter` in `rxjs` chain. So here is an example:

```
export interface SunInterface {
  brightness: number;
}

export interface MoonInterface {
  people: string[];
}

export class HelloComponent  {

  constructor() {
    const first_obs$: Observable<SunInterface> = of({ brightness: 100 });
    const second_obs$: Observable<MoonInterface> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next({ people: ['Neil Armstrong', 'Buzz Aldrin', 'Alan Bean'] });
      }, 2000)
    });

    combineLatest(
      first_obs$,
      second_obs$
    )
    .pipe(
      map(([sun, moon]) => {
        const filtred = moon.people.filter(astronaut => astronaut.startsWith('N'));
        return [sun, { ...moon, ...{ people: filtred }}]; // should I add type for arguments? 
      }),
      filter(([sun, moon]) => {
        console.log('1111', sun);
        console.log('2222', moon);
        return !!moon.people.length; // here I get a lint error
      })
    )
    .subscribe(([sun, moon]) => {
    })
  }
}
```

I got a lint error in the place where I left a comment in code `Property 'people' does not exist on type SunInterface | { people: string[] }`. I'm guessing I made something wrong with types. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try define it's `type` inside your pipeline

```
.....filter(([sun, moon]: [SunInterface, MoonInterface]) => ..... )
```

Comment: yes. thats true. but i did `return <[SunInterface, MoonInterface]>[sun, { ...moon, ...{ people: filtred }}];` I guess there is no difference.